# Desktop background image appearing only when external monitor is on the 'right' of netbook

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-10.04, desktop, external-display, desktop-customization

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. When I attach an external monitor the default is that the new monitor is placed to the **right** of the samsung n150 netbook I am using. This opens the desktop back ground on the screen, not duplicates though. When I go to System>preferences then monitors and change the screen to be on the left, the desktop background disappears and I cannot set it so that the background is still there.

My goal is to be able to rearrange the relative positions of the monitors without the desktop backgrounds being distorted.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Wezly I added the goal more explicity

Comment: Did you try moving around in the workspaces? (Ctrl+Alt+ArrowKey)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that if you are extending the desktop instead of cloning, then you will be able to have different backgrounds on each screen. maybe this is where you are having trouble?